# Scala 3 generic tuples: type bound & converting to Seq

Tags: scala, generics, types, tuples

I have two problems, which I think are related.

I want to have a type for tuples, of which all elements of the tuple are at least an `Animal`, in Scala 3.3.1. I came up with the following:

```scala
// In ReproDef.scala
object ReproDef {
  type SubtypeTuple[T, L <: Tuple] <: Tuple = L match {
    case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
    case head *: tail => AsSubtype[T, head]#Out *: SubtypeTuple[T, tail]
  }

  class AsSubtype[T, U] {
    type Out = U
  }

  given [T, U <: T]: AsSubtype[T, U] = new AsSubtype[T, U]

  sealed trait Animal
  case class Cat() extends Animal
  case class Dog() extends Animal
  case class Bird() extends Animal

  val validTuple: SubtypeTuple[Cat | Dog | Bird, (Cat, Dog, Bird)] = Cat() *: Dog() *: Bird() *: EmptyTuple
  val validTuple2: SubtypeTuple[Animal, (Animal, Animal)] = (Cat(), Dog())
  val validTuple3: (Animal, Animal) = validTuple2

  def toSeq[L <: Tuple](tup: SubtypeTuple[Animal, L]): Seq[Animal] = {
    tup match {
      case empty: EmptyTuple => Seq.empty
      case (head: Animal) *: (tail: SubtypeTuple[Animal, tail_]) => head +: toSeq(tail)
    }
  }
}
```

(Full disclosure: I had a different solution, which worked, but was less readable. The above code is generated with ChatGPT, but should do the same, afaict. At least the errors I get are identical.)

Now here comes my first question: is there a better way to formulate this concept of a tuple where each element is at least a certain type T?

My second question is that I want to be able to convert tuples containing only animals to Sequences of Animals. The Tuple type contains a `toList` method, but that works only sometimes:

```scala
// In ReproUse.scala
def foo(): Unit = {
  val sig: (ReproDef.Cat, ReproDef.Dog) = (ReproDef.Cat(), ReproDef.Dog())
  def myId(x: Tuple): Tuple = x
  val x: Seq[ReproDef.Animal] = myId(sig).toList // Compiler error, see below
  println(myId(sig).toList) // Works, also without myId of course
}
```

Compiler error:

```
Found:    List[Tuple.Union[(?1 : Tuple)]]
Required: Seq[testdyn.ReproDef.Animal]

where:    ?1 is an unknown value of type Tuple


Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:

  trying to reduce  Tuple.Union[(?1 : Tuple)]
  trying to reduce  scala.Tuple.Fold[(?1 : Tuple), Nothing, [x, y] =>> x | y]
  failed since selector  (?1 : Tuple)
  does not match  case EmptyTuple => Nothing
  and cannot be shown to be disjoint from it either.
  Therefore, reduction cannot advance to the remaining case

    case h *: t => h | scala.Tuple.Fold[t, Nothing, [x, y] =>> x | y] [7:35]
```

In hopes of avoiding this typecheck error, I also defined my own toSeq, see the very first code snippet. However, that also gives a type error:

```scala
// In ReproUse.scala
def bar(): Unit = {
  val sig: (ReproDef.Cat, ReproDef.Dog) = (ReproDef.Cat(), ReproDef.Dog())
  println(ReproDef.toSeq(sig))
}
```

Error:

```
Found:    (sig : (testdyn.ReproDef.Cat, testdyn.ReproDef.Dog))
Required: testdyn.ReproDef.SubtypeTuple[testdyn.ReproDef.Animal, L]

where:    L is a type variable with constraint <: Tuple


Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:

  trying to reduce  testdyn.ReproDef.SubtypeTuple[testdyn.ReproDef.Animal, L]
  failed since selector  L
  does not match  case EmptyTuple => EmptyTuple
  and cannot be shown to be disjoint from it either.
  Therefore, reduction cannot advance to the remaining case

    case head *: tail => testdyn.ReproDef.AsSubtype[testdyn.ReproDef.Animal, head]#Out *:
  testdyn.ReproDef.SubtypeTuple[testdyn.ReproDef.Animal, tail] [14:28]
```

My custom `toSeq` method does work in the file `ReproDef.scala`, the problem starts occurring only when I want to use that method outside the file.

I think I am simply getting confused where the boundary is for typechecking, and I am probably expecting too much. Can someone explain to me my oversight, and what kind of type annotations I have to add to get these small examples to compile? Or is there maybe a better match type I can use that Scala 3 can work with better? The main motivaiton for this question is that I will probably use this toSeq method quite a few times, so I'd like it to cause as few type annotations as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1: Is this one line solution enough? ([test it on line](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/p1TJUqaCSR6sgqc0qRSyjA))

```
type SubtypeTuple[E >: Tuple.Union[T], T <: Tuple] = T
```

A2: You should change

```
def foo(): Unit = {
  val sig: (ReproDef.Cat, ReproDef.Dog) = (ReproDef.Cat(), ReproDef.Dog())
  def myId(x: Tuple): Tuple = x
  val x: Seq[ReproDef.Animal] = myId(sig).toList // Compiler error, see below
  println(myId(sig).toList) // Works, also without myId of course
}
```

to

```
//...
  def myId[T <: Tuple](x: T): T = x
//...
```

Since your method droped the type information of T.

**Edit** According to your comments, I think you need typeclass for type constraint instead. Something like:

```
scala> trait Animals[T]:
     |     def values(animals: T): Seq[Animal]
     |
     | object Animals:
     |     given Animals[EmptyTuple] = animals => Nil
     |     given [H <: Animal, T <: Tuple : Animals]: Animals[H *: T] =
     |         case h *: tail => h +: summon[Animals[T]].values(tail)
     |

scala> class Zoo[T: Animals](animals: T):
     |     def toSeq: Seq[Animal] = summon[Animals[T]].values(animals)
     |
// defined class Zoo

scala> Zoo((Dog(), Cat(), Bird())).toSeq
val res0: Seq[Animal] = List(Dog(), Cat(), Bird())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Regarding A1: I was hoping for a type that constraints the Tuple without a type parameter, e.g. something like `type AnimalTuple = "any T where T < Tuple and Animal <: Tuple.Union[T]";`, but maybe that's me wanting too much. Your fix for A2 works perfectly, but I still don't understand why my last code snippet would give an error...

Comment: My goal is to be able to write the tuple subtyping as a type constraint. With the `SubtypeTuple` structure I can't write something like this: `trait F[T <: SubtypeTuple[T]]: ...`. Instead I have to add the subtypetuple constraint as a member: `trait F[T <: Tuple]: def t: SubtypeTuple[Animal, T]`. Or should I make a new question for this?